# How to save session data in prod server?

Tags: 8, sessions

I want to save my data in a session: under drupal 8.6

I worked with "**Private tempstore**" it works locally but not in the server prod only if user is ***anonymous***.

```
if ($this->currentUser->isAnonymous()) {
  session_start();
}
```

The same for the **native php session**.

I ask if it can be stored with php **configuration** or how?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use procedural code. Session is now a Symfony object:

```
class MymoduleSessionCounter {
  function increment(Request $request) {
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $value = $session->get('mymodule_count', 0);
    $session->set('mymodule_count', $value + 1);

    return $value;
  }
}
```

Source: https://www.drupal.org/node/2380327

**Edit:**

What you need to do for debugging depends on your dev environment. If for example you have disabled caching you are not able to debug caching issues. In this case enable caching in dev and see what happens if you add cache metadata to the returned result:

```
    return [
      '#markup' => $value,
      '#cache' => ['max-age' => 0],
    ];
```

Cache max-age = 0, because the result in this example changes on each request and is not worth caching.

When this is working the next step is to optimize production performance. Put the code in a [#lazy_builder](https://www.drupal.org/node/2498803) callback or in a block, which is built lazily by default. In both cases this is then [auto-placeholdered](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/auto-placeholdering) for certain cache condition like cache max-age = 0, so that the rest of the page can still be cached.

Comment: That doesn't work, I use Drupal 8.6 not Drupal 8.0

Comment: This code example works only in a controller (for any D8 version). If you want to get the request in other places you need to adjust the first line. Where is your code placed?

Comment: it placed in controller, that work in my local environnement but not for prod

Comment: I don't know what you mean, the referenced change record is for production code.

Comment: It seems likely that there is some other difference making it fail in production vs. development.

Comment: @greggles, ideally there is no difference between dev and prod. It's unclear what the question is then about, because the question doesn't contain any details about the differences between dev and prod.

Comment: Yes, totally agreed @4k4.

Answer (score 0):

that also can be resolved with this code in rending controller :

```
$output = [];

$output['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
```

https://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/340/disable-cache-for-a-specific-page